# RAILS 6 Prevent many slashes in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How can I prevent Rails 6 to proceed a GET URL that contain many "/" ?

Example :

```
route.rb
get "test/testB", to: "test/testB#show"
```

RAILS will be able to access these URLs :

```
http://localhost///test/testB
http://localhost/////////test/testB
...
```

Thanks for your advice,
Thomas

Comment: do you want the system to error when it gets these URLs, or to correct them?

Comment: Yes correct or reject (route not found) this URL

Comment: I've never done it, but in your routes file you should be able to use a "redirect" with "constraints" set to look for extra slashes.  Other than that, I'd control it in the web-server configuration itself, depending on the web-server that configuration would be very different